# вытащить информацию из обьекта

Tags: php

У меня в php файл через POST приходит обьект с вот такой вот структурой

```
 rpc: {"job":"space.truncate","params":{"space":"person","index":1,"key":["11"],"hostname":"tarantool","port":3301,"username":"guest","password":""}}
```

мне нужно достать отсюда значение key, если обратиться через переменную вот так
`$test = $_POST['rpc']` - то я достану только то что внутри rpc (то есть вообще все что пришло), как мне правильно обратиться чтобы достать именно значение key?

Comment: `$_POST['rpc']['params']['key'][0]` ?

Comment: Вам приходят данные в формате json. Нужно обработать [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: никогда не сталкивался с такой обработкой, а как правильно обработать?

Comment: `json_decode($data)` - "делает" из json-строки php объект, если передавать второй параметр (прим. json_decode($data, true)) то json-строка "превратится" в массив

Comment: @MoloF и получим ошибку _Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in ..._

Comment: @ InDevX А можете показать на моем примере как правильно применить?

Comment: @АнтонКравцов как-то так - `json_decode($_POST['rpc'], 1)['params']['key']`

Comment: @MoloF так-то я имел ввиду что вы декодируете строку в объект а не в массив

Answer (score 2):

декодируйте данные и извлеките нужное

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['rpc']);
$keys = $data->params->key;
print_r($keys);
 // либо
$data = json_decode($_POST['rpc'],true);
$keys = $data['params']['key'];
```

Comment: @InDevX пофиксил